# JavaFX Same textarea with different Pane's

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I have a project with maven, javafx and fxml. I have one main BorderPane, `welcome.fxml`, and Pane, `ready.fxml`.

My start method is;

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

    try {
      Pane root = (Pane) FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("welcome.fxml"));
      Scene scene = new Scene(root, 640, 480);
      primaryStage.setScene(scene);
      primaryStage.show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      makeAlert(e, false);
    }
}
```

Now, I have a button in my `welcome.fxml`, and I want to change my BorderPane's center with `ready.fxml`. Here is my button handler;

```
@FXML
private void buttonHandler() throws IOException, InterruptedException {


    stage = (Stage) myButton.getScene().getWindow();
    Pane sub = (Pane) FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("../ready.fxml"));
    BorderPane root = (BorderPane) FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("../welcome.fxml"));
    root.setCenter(sub);

    //Scene scene = new Scene(root, 640, 480);
    //stage.getScene().setRoot(root);
}
```

**UPDATE**: Here is my mistake,as @James_D noticed, I load `welcome.fxml` again in my controller and so, my whole Scene changes insted of only center.

The correct way should be;

```
stage = (Stage) brokerConnect.getScene().getWindow();
Pane center = (Pane) FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("../ready.fxml"));
// FIXME: Get root like this
BorderPane root = (BorderPane) stage.getScene().getRoot();
root.setCenter(center);
```

EDITED: Java codes added.

Comment: Why are you replacing the whole root of the scene if you only want to replace the center of the border pane? As it stands, your question doesn't really lend itself to an answer... I suggest you create a [MCVE] and [edit] your question to include it. Explain how the behavior you get differs from the behavior you want.

Comment: After I  execute this , ` root.setCenter(newPane);`  the center not changed, so I replace rootScene. I just started to learn JavaFX, sorry for my ignorance.

Comment: Then you're doing something wrong in the code you haven't shown us. It's not that you don't know JavaFX that's frustrating here, it's that you posted a question without any of the information anyone would need to answer it.

Comment: I'm sorry, you're definitely right. I added my codes, and hope it is better know.

Comment: It looks like you are loading a new copy of the border pane from `welcome.fxml` and replacing the center of that new copy, instead of replacing the center of the one that was originally loaded and displayed. If you could be bothered to create a [MCVE] we would be able to know for sure that's what's happening and give you a way to fix it.

Comment: @James_D, you are right, I just figured out that. I will edit my question as you suggested. I though loading fxml file will give me same Pane.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126546/discussion-between-black-glix-and-james-d).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should update the center of the *existing* border pane, not create a new one and set the center of the new one.

All you need is to inject the border pane into the controller in the usual way. So add a `fx:id` to the root element of `welcome.fxml`:

```xml
<!-- imports, etc... -->
<BorderPane fx:id="root" fx:controller="..." xmlns:fx="..." ... >
    <!-- ... -->
</BorderPane>
```

And then in the controller

```
public class Controller { /* or whatever name you have, again, you can't be bothered to post a MCVE */

    @FXML
    private BorderPane root ;

    @FXML
    private void buttonHandler() throws IOException {
        Pane sub = (Pane) FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("../ready.fxml"));
        root.setCenter(sub);
    }

    // ...
}
```